# O que causa esse erro?

Tags: laravel

O sistema estava funcionando normalmente. De repente me aparece esta mensagem de erro:
**`Error in exception handler: View [errors.message] not found. in /home/storage/b/24/ff/...`**

Não consigo logar no sistema.
Qual a causa provável e como devo proceder para solucionar isso?

Comment: Rapaz, o problema é exatamente o que está sendo exibido: "A view [errors.message] não foi encontrada.". Tenta confirmar se ela realmente existe.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, Guilherme. Trocaram a senha do banco de dados e não me avisaram. Já solucionei.

Comment: Resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Sim. Está resolvido.

Comment: Vou converter para uma resposta, então.

Comment: Ok, Guilherme..

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz, o problema é exatamente o que está sendo exibido:

> A view [errors.message] não foi encontrada.

Tenta confirmar se ela realmente existe.